# Php mailer missing string from FromName

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer version 5.2.22 and losing some part of string from FromName.

For e.g.

Mail sent with FromName : "CONC, abcø"

Outputs FromName : "abcø"

String part "CONC," is removed from FromName of mail received.

Code sample :

```
<?php
    $email = 'waleedAhmed@mymail.com';
    $name = 'waleed';
    $event_info[0]['organizer_name'] = 'CONC, abcø';
    $subject = 'Testing..';
    $content = ' content : '. $event_info[0]['organizer_name'];

    $objName = new \PHPMailer();
    $objName->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $objName->Mailer = "smtp";
    $objName->Host = "mail.mymail.com";
    $objName->Port = 25;
    $objName->Mailer = "sendmail";
    $objName->From = 'donotreply@mymail.com';
    $objName->Sender = 'donotreply@mymail.com';
    $objName->FromName = $event_info[0]['organizer_name']
    $objName->IsHTML(true);
    $objName->Body = $content;
    $objName->Send();
    unset($objName);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - it works perfectly for me. The header is correctly encoded as `From: =?UTF-8?Q?CONC=2C_abc=C3=B8?= <donotreply@mymail.com>`. You are using an old version, and it looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example.

Comment: Yes, I am using version 5.2.22. And I am even getting same headers. Anyhow thanks. Below mentioned solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ' \"CONC, abcø\" < donotreply@mymail.com > ';   

$objName->FromName = '\"'.$event_info[0]['organizer_name'].'\" < donotreply@mymail.com >';
```

Working fine.

Comment: Header I got is : From: =?UTF-8?Q?\"CONC,_abc=C3=B8\"_<_donotreply@mymail.com_>

Didn't found reason how it worked.. Still curious.

Comment: Getting "\" at end of string on MAC and GMAIL. Removal of "\" doesn't makes sense but it works better : 

$objName->FromName = '\"'.$event_info[0]['organizer_name'].'" < donotreply@mymail.com >';